# http request not receiving intended response(or is not being parsed)[webkit form boundary]

Tags: html, delphi, winsock, recaptcha, wininet

I am creating a simple application that will let the user manage his/her Aeria Games) account.
I intend to use this to create a side-app for a certain game that I play.
My problem, is that when I send the request, it sends a response that looks exactly like the get request version(yes I know, WEIRD) and doesn't change anything(e-mail I am currently trying to change, but I also want to do password management(after all, what's an account management app without a password changer)).

Here is a successful HTTP POST request that changes the e-mail(I used fiddler to capture my browser's http request).

```
POST http://www.aeriagames.com/user/92466845/edit/account HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://www.aeriagames.com/user/92466845/edit/account
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 1589
DNT: 1
Host: www.aeriagames.com
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: __utmc=71836108; lang=en; __utma=71836108.1752246952.1385652238.1385867504.1385918072.10; __utmz=71836108.1385596659.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); utm_ref=http://www.aeriagames.com/; __utmv=71836108.|1=v_sp=0=1^2=v_age=34=1^3=v_gen=NA=1^4=v_acct=0=1; _gaUniversalX=GA1.2.1752246952.1385652238; __gads=ID=1f31e24ad29d5444:T=1385669247:S=ALNI_MbSMtFcxyx6woFbnCDcXByJCbzrKA; __utmb=71836108.22.9.1385918564155; ag_signup_completed=1; AGESESSID=ed691e273007a36397cb1d3bd4e69f3a; AGESESSID_SIG=NWZkOGMxNjNlYzZkY2Y1OGYwYTY5MzNkNjE3NzM3NTMyZjFhNGZkZnxlZDY5MWUyNzMwMDdhMzYzOTdjYjFkM2JkNGU2OWYzYXwkMmEkMTAkQUdTWG0uNXVydnRtY2NwU3JITWk3ZXdKcXBJdXF5YzFzR1A0NUZlSXZiQy9QYThTUkZ3OWF8OTI0NjY4NDV8dWdnaTAzMXwxMzg1OTE4NTU0; AGESESSID_data=a%3A3%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22userid%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%2292466845%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%22autologinid%22%3Bs%3A33%3A%221034996301529b705a714616.82880917%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%22user_active%22%3Bi%3A1%3B%7D; __ar_v4=AF2ADDNNHFDFBJXGZLJI2M%3A20131129%3A17%7CQD7EQLJLZRDDNJQQR47BLX%3A20131129%3A17%7CY25KFQ7YFRFMFIIQ5CUA4W%3A20131129%3A17

-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="edit[mail]"

vigudwea@sharklasers.com
-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="edit[pass_current_for_mail]"

JX04utgjamezv0
-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="edit[pass_current]"


-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="edit[pass][pass1]"


-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="edit[pass][pass2]"


-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="edit[change_email]"

1
-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="edit[change_pass]"

0
-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="edit[form_token]"

eae5053f2a1ba7844992bdd273d327a9
-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="edit[form_id]"

user_edit
-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recaptcha_challenge_field"

03AHJ_Vuskvi0iTL9Xkw8rgXRTSdIUKXau6IN4MnP00MdBMTd5Suzl6Px2fsg0VlDFnSeVEHlYKhwTlSiG5aS6KjorEHzRbS7doFsgCACSL8ZyLWDaEy9-RaPvC5ivxjhrPFCjLXM4YufV8_Ezxuo4pDsnEyn6tvmUJZzCwhGmbOOOZuMmcD9ITTs
-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recaptcha_response_field"

James lmndme
-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="op"

Submit
-----------------------------7dd3e30504ac--
```

Why did I leave that e-mail and pass there? The e-mail has been changed again, so it won't work if you tried to login to the site(I don't want to edit any details in case that was the problem).
Yes, the password is correct.

(fiddler doesn't log the http request/response from winsock so i'll have to just post the response from the function).
after the function sends the xx data it should respond with a redirect(In the header), but it doesn't!...

You can get the units here:
http://pastebin.com/f2EemQjS (AeriaAPI.pas)

http://pastebin.com/VNsj9ZwB (uFunc.pas)

and here is usage example:

```
Procedure Aeria(user, pass:string);
var
  val:String;
  a:TAeria;
label 
  restart1, restart2, restart3;
begin
  a := TAeria.Create(user, pass);
  if a.Error = INVALID_CAPTCHA then 
  begin

restart1:

    if not GetCaptcha(a) then 
    begin
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('PID 0x' + RandomID + ' exited.');
      Exit;
    end;
    a.ReLogin(user, pass);
    if a.Error = INVALID_CAPTCHA then 
      goto restart1;
  end;
  if (a.Error = INVALID_CREDENTIALS) then 
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Invalid username or password!');
    Exit;
  end;
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Successfully logged in!');

restart2:

  if not( a.GetData() ) then 
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('an unknown error occured!');
    Exit;
  end;

  if not GetCaptcha(a) then 
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Logging out...');
    InternetSetCookie('https://www.aeriagames.com/', nil, '');
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Logged out!');
    Exit;
  end;

  if not a.AeriaSetEmail('xjxqkdqu@sharklasers.com') then//sywjozjc@sharklasers.com'
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(a.Error));

  if a.Error = INVALID_CAPTCHA then 
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('invalid captcha!');
    goto restart2;
  end;
  if a.Error <> INVALID_NONE then 
  begin
    case a.Error of
      INVALID_PASSWORD:
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('invalid password!');
      INVALID_TOKEN:
        goto restart2;
      INVALID_COOKIES:
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('error: session expired!');
      INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('invalid password or username!');
      INVALID_UNKNOWN:
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('an unknown error occured!');
    end;
    Exit;
  end;
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Part[1] of [2] Complete.');

restart3:

  if not(a.GetData()) then 
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('an unknown error occured!');
    Exit;
  end;
  if not GetCaptcha(a) then 
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Logging out...');
    InternetSetCookie('https://www.aeriagames.com', nil, '');
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Logged out!');
    Exit;
  end;
  a.AeriaSetPass('Aefow40tu943kszdfg');
  if a.Error = INVALID_CAPTCHA then 
    goto restart3;
  if a.Error <> INVALID_NONE then 
  begin
    case a.Error of
      INVALID_PASSWORD:
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('invalid password!');
      INVALID_TOKEN:
        goto restart3;
      INVALID_COOKIES:
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('error: session expired!');
      INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('invalid password or username!');
      INVALID_UNKNOWN:
        Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('an unknown error occured!');
    end;
    Exit;
  end;
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('successful.');
end;
```

The example will fail with errorcode = 99 & then exit.

some questions you might ask:
Question:why am I using winsock for the HTTPPostRequest function?
Answer: I thought the WININET version of the function it was the problem, so I decided to use pure winsock for that function.

Q: Did I call WSAStartUp() xD?
A: Yes, I have Dx.

Q: I am using winsock, so how do I check for the re-direct?
A: I use showmessage(recvstr); after the header is received, and it just responds without the redirect :/

Q: why not just drop a TWebBrower on the form and have the user change his pass from that?
A: why not make the process more simple on the user-end?

I've worked on this problem for days, you guys are my LAST hope...I am NOT asking for a copy+paste, I do NOT want a copy+paste answer, I just want someone to point me to where I messed up so I can learn from my mistake(s).

This project is really not needed, but what if I come across a problem like this when I actually do start programming as a "job"...

Comment: Please format your code (already done by me). Try to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) your code. Do not refer to global variables like Form1. Try to avoid goto. - This will not help you with your actual problem, but help you and others to get into your code :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out!
For anyone who has the same problem as me:

the "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" header is the boundary minus the two dashes("-")

example:
if your boundary is:
-----------------------------7dd37b37e06e2
you send:
---------------------------7dd37b37e06e2

hope I helped someone! It took me 3 ENTIRE days to solve this problem :(